# How to write test for hooks by onclick method?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing

How do I write a test to activate the save button when I choose a date in the datepicker and the onclick function, which holds a state?here is a code snippet....

```
        if (selectedDate?.filter((e: any) => e.employeeId === employeeId).length > 0) {

            setSelectedDate(selectedDate.map((e: any) => {

                if (e.employeeId === employeeId) {

                    return { ...e, workAnniversary: value }

                }

                else {

                    return { ...e }

                }

            }))

        }



        else {

            setSelectedDate([...selectedDate, { employeeId: employeeId, workAnniversary: value }])

        }

        setIsDisabled(false);

    };
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What testing framework are you using? Are you getting stuck on something specific?

Comment: @Evert I'm using the React testing library, but I don't know how to test the date picker's onchange feature because I'm new to testing